# How to Validate a Xero webhook payload with HMACSHA256 in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, xero-api

I need to validate `Xero webhook` in PHP. Here's My Code

```
     $payload = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $webhookKey = '-----Webhook Key-----';
        $computedSignatureKey = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $webhookKey, true));

        if ($computedSignatureKey === $_SERVER['HTTP_X_XERO_SIGNATURE']) {
            return response(200);
        }

return response(401);
```

suppose the xero signature is `= aQGh6OxbmgB1NQnnKrQt0utlrqC4dbAJSC2/Aa2/IE4=`
and above code return hashed value is `= aQGh6OxbmgB1NQnnKrQt0utlrqC4dbAJSC2KAa2/IE4=`

there's a difference between both values, difference is slash (/)

signature coming from `xero` include `(/)` but after hashed it removes `(/)` and replace it with alphabet

so I can't validate `Intent to receive`

`Webhook` it always return to this status

`Intent to receive` required
Response to incorrectly signed payload not `401`. Learn more

Answer (score 1):

With intent to receive, a mixture of correctly and incorrectly signed packages are sent to test the way you handle both.

Incorrectly signed packages typically only differ from the correct signature by 1 changed digit eg the /

Xero is expecting your server to send a 401 code when the signatures don't match. Your PHP code above only has an if condition returning a code 200, there is no else condition returning a code 401.

Comment: yes, But how i can validate it , is there's any issue in my above code or anything else to do.  i implemented else condition but its for returning response 401.